# Bond dissociation energy among halogens

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory

Among the halogens, why is it that the fluorine has the lowest bond dissociation enthalpy, considering the fact that fluorine is the smallest and the internuclear distance between the fluorine molecule is least and $2p-2p$ overlap should also very very strong ,the bond dissociation enthalpy should have been very high but it is lowest among the halogens. Why is it so??

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43200/why-is-fluorine-more-reactive-than-iodine-despite-the-weaker-i-i-bond